# JSDoc - How to document a parameter that is being ignored `function f(_, otherParam) {}`

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have the following code:

```
const renderRightActions = (_, dragX) => {
  const trans = dragX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50, 100, 101],
    outputRange: [60, 110, 110, 110],
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX: trans }] }}>
      <RectButton
        onPress={handleOnDeleteButtonPress}
        style={[
          styles.trashIconContainer,
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.primary,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Icon
          name="trash-can"
          type="material-community"
          size={26}
          color={colors.white}
        />
      </RectButton>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

As you can see, I am ignoring the first argument of the method using the underscore character.

How can I document it in JSDoc? I have tried this:

```
/**
 * Renders the right actions for the `Swipeable`.
 *
 * @param {any} _ - Ignored parameter.
 * @param {Animated.AnimatedInterpolation} dragX - Drag X value.
 * @returns {React.ReactNode} The `Swipeable` right action.
 */
```

But not sure if there is any standardized way to handle this situation. Any ideas?

Comment: JSDoc should still describe the parameter even if you don't use it. What if you come back to the code in 6 months, without completely debugging everything can you figure out what the ignored value is

Comment: mmm okey, then I will describe the parameter disabling the linting error.